# How to calculate the number of possible decision trees of given feature-target set?

Tags: cart

Is there a method to calculate the search space of decision trees for different depth values?

Let's assume we have 5 binary feature and 1 binary target.

How can we calculate that how many possible decision tree can be produced?

What if we want to get just the set of decision trees only whose have depth(high-level) 3.