# Counting number of possible decision trees

Tags: cart, combinatorics

I spent a lot of time on this question, and I search extensively on the internet, but I cannot find an answer (only an unanswered question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517966/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-decision-trees-of-given-feature-target-s)).

Assume we have $p$ binary covariates, so that for each covariate we have only one single potential split. How many distinct binary decision trees can I generate?

From my calculation, I can generate $p$ distinct trees with 2 leaves, $2 p (p - 1)$ 3-leaf trees, and $p (p - 1)^2 + 4 p (p - 1) (p - 2)$ 4-leaf trees. Beyond that, it gets really confusing, and I cannot extrapolate any general formula from my results so far.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be *distinct* and what counts as a *tree.*  (For instance, you write about "potential split" as if some nodes might have only one immediate descendant.)  In most cases it's possible to develop a useful recursion.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/368/counting-binary-trees for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, I will try to dive into the details there. By tree, I mean binary decision trees (CART is the standard implementation), i.e., the machine learning algorithm (as described, among many others, by Hastie and coauthors in "Elements of Statistical Learning").